# Issue with Heroku ChromeWebDriver and Chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, heroku

I have python app deployed on heroku which uses selenium. I use this chromedriver: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver and this Google_Chrome_bin: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome .
I declared them in the settings of app as buildpacks and while starting my app I am getting this Exception:

selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 93
Current browser version is 92.0.4515.107 with binary path /app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome

How can I resolve the issue on heroku? Thank u for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set your Chromedriver version by setting `CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION` in your heroku app settings. (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver)

You will want to choose a version compatible with your version of chrome. You can see current releases here:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Given your exact error message, I suggest setting the version to 92.0.4515.43

Comment: What about setting the actual version of CHROME? For me, on every new bump up in chromeversion, my CHROME is also automatically updated. How to stop this?

Comment: It's not working ATM.